# Creating an instance inside an instance in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I have a `TemperatureSensor` class that creates `OneWire` and `DallasTemperature` within itself and exposes the actual temperature. The problem is that when I create it, it doesn't work. I sense a very weird behavior related to the scope of objects created inside the `Attach` method.

If I supply a `DallasTemperature` instance from outside to the `Attach` method, then all works fine. If I try to instantiate it within a class - then the sketch doesn't work, the temperature is constantly `-127.0C`.

I tried instantiating the members in the constructor initialization list - same result.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

class CTemperatureSensor {
    private:
        OneWire *ow;
        DallasTemperature *dt;
        float toF(float c);
    public:
        float Celsius;
        float Fahrenheit;
        void Attach(uint8_t SignalPin, DallasTemperature *_dt = NULL);
        void Read();
};

void CTemperatureSensor::Attach(uint8_t SignalPin, DallasTemperature *_dt) {
    if (_dt == NULL) {
        // This branch does not work: the sensor returns -127.0.
        // All other devices behave in the same way:
        // instantiating an object inside another object creates weird behavior.
        ow = &OneWire(SignalPin);
        dt = &DallasTemperature(ow);
    } else {
        // When OneWire and DallasTemperature are declared directly in the sketch
        // and supplied as a refence, all seems to work.
        dt = _dt;
    }
    pinMode(SignalPin, INPUT);
    Celsius = 0;
    Fahrenheit = toF(Celsius);
}

void CTemperatureSensor::Read() {
    dt->requestTemperatures(); 
    Celsius = dt->getTempCByIndex(0);
    Fahrenheit = toF(Celsius);
}

float CTemperatureSensor::toF(float c) {
    return (c * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32.0; }
```

Comment: `dt = &DallasTemperature(ow);` the object is a temporary object created on stack. you have to use `dt = new DallasTemperature(ow);`

Comment: @Juraj Thank you so much! This worked, and you should put this as an answer, so I can upvote.